# Did Achashverosh rule over the entire Old World?

Tags: history, geography, megillat-esther, tractate-megillah

[Megilla 11a says](http://dafyomi.co.il/megilah/points/mg-ps-011.htm) "Three ruled over the world - Achav, Achashverosh and Nebuchadnetzar." It suggests a few other names that weren't on the list and rejects them because they didn't rule over one territory or another.

Now, I think it's reasonable to exclude peoples living in the Americas and Australia from "the world" because, as the Gemara discusses above, "from Hodu until Kush" seems to be considered as the whole world, i.e. the [Old World](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_World). The question becomes, did Achashverosh indeed rule over the "whole (old) world"?

Or were there any peoples, like maybe [the Greeks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greece) or [the Chinese](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_China) that escaped his rule? For example, in [the Greco-Persian Wars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greco-Persian_Wars), Persia did invade Greece, although they weren't exactly successful. And in China, the [Eastern Zhou Dynasty of the time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zhou_Dynasty#Eastern_Zhou) seemed to be isolated from the Persians. Did he rule over them? Are these locations not what the Gemara is talking about (just like it's not talking about the Americas)??

It may also worth considering that the Gemara describes Achashverosh's reign as starting with 7 provinces, expanding to 20 (perhaps the 20 listed in the map below), and finally to 100 provinces (perhaps much more expanded but very temporarily?). However that theory seems to weaken later when the Gemrara says, "Daryavesh established his reign over 120 provinces" (in that he ruled over 7 less than Achashverosh).

Map of Achaemenid Empire at fullest extent:

[image: Map of Achaemenid Empire at fullest extent]

Comment: What about China? What about Native Americans?

Comment: @DoubleAA ask that!

Comment: @Yehoshua This one already does.

Comment: I think what @DoubleAA is obliquely getting it is that your question, though  its sources and arguments apply to many other areas of the world, focuses on Greece. I suggest (and I think this is also what DoubleAA meant) that you either [edit] into your question some reason that you think Greece might be different from, or at least more interesting to ask about than, China et al., or that you edit your question to generalize it, perhaps not mentioning Greece at all. (You do mention Persia's invasion of Greece, but to the extent that distinguishes Greece from China it *weakens* your question.)

Comment: @msh210 The reason for targeting my question as such was because when the Gemara argues that Cush and Hodu are at opposite ends of the world, presumably it refers only to the Old World (Native Americans excluded). I mentioned Greece and not other specific settlements because I knew off the top of my head there was a significant population there. Maybe I'll look into China's geography of the time and edit to include them too.

Comment: I suggest that you [edit] into your question your understanding of the _g'mara_ as referring to the old world (it currently explicitly says "did Achashverosh indeed rule over the whole world?"), so that you get the answers you're looking for and not (e.g.) ones that address whether the rules was over only the old world.

Comment: @msh210 Edited.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin Interesting. So how would he explain what the Gemara meant, that the whole world didn't in fact include the areas more distant to the Middle East? Side note, were the Macedonians that expansionist already, and since most Achaemenid kings were killed anyway what difference would that have made?

Comment: Historically, Nebuchadnezzar's [Babylonian empire](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neo-Babylonian_Empire) did not extend over Anatolia, Egypt or Persia (which is how Cyrus managed to conquer Babylon a couple of decades later).

Comment: See Ben Yehoyada there who provides a limited scope to the "world" ruled by Achashverosh.

Comment: I’d like to point out that the islands mentioned towards the end of the Megillah are generally accepted as not being part of Achashveroshs’ reign

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Achaemenid_Empire The Achaemenid Empire also called the First Persian Empire was an ancient Iranian empire based in Western Asia and founded by Cyrus the Great in 550 BC. It reached its greatest extent under Xerxes I, who conquered most of northern and central ancient Greece. At its greatest territorial extent, the Achaemenid Empire stretched from the Balkans and Eastern Europe in the west to the Indus Valley in the east. The empire was larger than any previous empire in history, spanning a total of 5.5 million square kilometers (2.1 million square miles).

Comment: Your question is tricky: you ask about sages' interpretation of a mythical story. Do you try to find the closest historical king and ask about a historical fact? Do you ask about sages' knowledge of history and geography? Do you ask about ways to interpret sages' ignorance metaphorically?

Comment: @AlBerko This was a question from 9 years ago. Essentially I asked it because it was a statement of Chazal I came across which seemed incorrect, and I was trying to figure out if they didn’t mean it literally, or if somehow they were actually right, or if they were actually in error. I’m still not sure if it is the first or third option.

Comment: @AL https://discord.gg/fPnWaQet

Comment: Thanks…But I never heard from you on Discord. Either way you can delete the comment with the Discord link.

Answer (score 1):

The Gemara you quoted says that Shlomo Hamelech also ruled the whole world, but he was not listed because he did not finish his reign. Rav Chaim Kanievsky in the beginning of Derech Emunah vol. 2  asks that if so, the entire world should have the kedusha of Eretz Yisrael, because כבוש רבים שמיה כבוש (oversimplified explanation: land conquered by the entire Jewish people under their king becomes part of Eretz Yisrael)?

He answers that when the Gemara says Shlomo Hamelech (and by extension the other kings listed) ruled the entire world, it does not mean his kingdom literally extended that far. It means his influence did. (Kind of like the American president being called "leader of the free world".)

This is also apparent from the Gemara's description of Achav. He was not the actual king of those countries, he just had enough power to force them to listen to him.

I also think that the Gemara only meant he had influence over the known world of the day, whatever that was.

[image]

Comment: Very informative answer. It would be best if you understood that rabbis could only know as far as the historians of their times, and therefore each later rabbi reinterprets the texts to fit new empirical findings. Early rabbis who had no idea about real history took the scriptures pretty literally, for example, the imaginary kingdom of Solomon.

Comment: @AlBerko Please reread my answer more carefully. I demonstrate that the text never claimed these kings empires extended over the whole world, just their influence. I believe you are confusing actual scholars with people in general, who just repeat things without analyzing them.

Comment: I completely understood that. I merely attribute the attempt to re-interpret texts metaphorically to the empirical findings. I.e. once everybody around us knows it did not exist, we turn to metaphors.

Comment: @AlBerko You just repeated yourself? This is not an attempt to reinterpret texts, it is fixing a popular misconception.

Answer (score 0):

The meddrash ( ester rabbi 1:5 ) says …….that Koresh ruled the whole world and achahverosh inherited it from him .
But then he lost half ,due to vashti convincing
him stopping binyan bais hamikdash

Comment: Where does the meddrash say this?

Comment: אסתר רבה     א.   פסיק ה

Comment: You should put that in your answer.